# Segmentation fault in mpi_gather using fortran derived datatypes

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, mpi, openmpi, derived-types

I've been trying to write a program that computes the many millions of dipole-dipole interaction tensors as well as its derivatives. Because these tensors are trivially parallelizable, and often degenerate, I've decided to construct a lookup table (LUT) and distribute the work. Ultimately, they will be combined into a large matrix and diagonalized (I'll use scalapack for this eventually. For now, the diag fits on a node of nersc). To keep track of all the indices in fortran, I've constructed a couple derived data types.

```
type dtlrdr_lut
    sequence
    integer p
    integer q
    integer s
    integer i
    integer ind
    real(dp), dimension(3,3) :: dtlrdr
end type dtlrdr_lut

type dtlrdh_lut
    sequence
    integer p
    integer q
    integer ind
    real(dp), dimension(3, 3) :: TLR
    real(dp), dimension(3, 3, 3, 3) :: dTLRdh
end type dtlrdh_lut
```

In my subroutine where I want to parallelize all of this, I have:

```
    type(dtlrdr_lut), dimension(:), allocatable :: my_dtlrdr, collected_dtlrdr
    type(dtlrdh_lut), dimension(:), allocatable :: my_dtlrdh, collected_dtlrdh
    integer :: dh_dtype, dr_dtype, dh_types(5), dr_types(6), dh_blocks(5), dr_blocks(6)
    INTEGER(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: dh_offsets(5), dr_offsets(6)
    if(.not.allocated(my_dtlrdh))    allocate(my_dtlrdh(my_num_pairs))
    if(.not.allocated(my_dtlrdr))    allocate(my_dtlrdr(my_num_pairs*3*nat))

    if(me_image.eq.root_image) then
        if(.not.allocated(collected_dtlrdh))    allocate(collected_dtlrdh(num_pairs))
        if(.not.allocated(collected_dtlrdr))    allocate(collected_dtlrdr(num_pairs*3*nat))
        end if
    call mpi_get_address(my_dtlrdr(1)%p,      dr_offsets(1), ierr)
    call mpi_get_address(my_dtlrdr(1)%q,      dr_offsets(2), ierr)
    call mpi_get_address(my_dtlrdr(1)%s,      dr_offsets(3), ierr)
    call mpi_get_address(my_dtlrdr(1)%i,      dr_offsets(4), ierr)
    call mpi_get_address(my_dtlrdr(1)%ind,    dr_offsets(5), ierr)
    call mpi_get_address(my_dtlrdr(1)%dtlrdr, dr_offsets(6), ierr)
    do i = 2, size(dr_offsets)
      dr_offsets(i) = dr_offsets(i) - dr_offsets(1)
    end do
    dr_offsets(1) = 0
    dr_types = (/MPI_INTEGER, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION/)
    dr_blocks = (/1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3*3/)
    call mpi_type_struct(6, dr_blocks, dr_offsets, dr_types, dr_dtype, ierr)
    call mpi_type_commit(dr_dtype, ierr)

    call mpi_get_address(my_dtlrdh(1)%p,      dh_offsets(1), ierr)
    call mpi_get_address(my_dtlrdh(1)%q,      dh_offsets(2), ierr)
    call mpi_get_address(my_dtlrdh(1)%ind,    dh_offsets(3), ierr)
    call mpi_get_address(my_dtlrdh(1)%TLR,    dh_offsets(4), ierr)
    call mpi_get_address(my_dtlrdh(1)%dTLRdh, dh_offsets(5), ierr)
    do i = 2, size(dh_offsets)
      dh_offsets(i) = dh_offsets(i) - dh_offsets(1)
    end do
    dh_offsets(1) = 0
    dh_types = (/MPI_INTEGER, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION/)
    dh_blocks = (/1, 1, 1, 3*3, 3*3*3*3/)
    call mpi_type_struct(5, dh_blocks, dh_offsets, dh_types, dh_dtype, ierr)
    call mpi_type_commit(dh_dtype, ierr)
    call mpi_gather(my_dtlrdh, my_num_pairs, dh_dtype, &
                     collected_dtlrdh, num_pairs, dh_dtype, &
                     root_image, intra_image_comm)
    call mp_barrier(intra_image_comm)

    call mpi_gather(my_dtlrdr, my_num_pairs*3*nat, dr_dtype, &
                     collected_dtlrdr, num_pairs*3*nat, dr_dtype, &
                     root_image, intra_image_comm)
```

What is the result of the code? Well, the root process gathered and got to be barrier and then seg faulted:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
   Backtrace for this error:
    #0  0x10bac04f2
    #1  0x10bac0cae
    #2  0x7fff8d7c1f19
```

In this simulation on process 0:

```
size(my_dtlrdh) = 97
size(collected_dtlrdh) = 194
size(my_dtlrdr) = 873
size(collected_dtlrdr) = 1746
```

and on process 1

```
size(my_dtlrdh) = 97
size(collected_dtlrdh) = 3
size(my_dtlrdr) = 873
size(collected_dtlrdr) = 1650521
```

When I print the offsets, blocks, etc for process 0, I get:

```
printing dr vars           0
dr_blocks =  1  1  1  1  1  9
dr_offsets = 0  4  8  12 16 24
dr_types =   7  7  7  7  7  17
dr_dtype =   73

printing dh vars 0
dr_blocks =  1  1  1  9  81
dr_offsets = 0  4  8  16 88
dr_types =   7  7  7  17 17
dr_dtype =   74
```

and for process 1, I get:

```
printing dr vars  1
dr_blocks =   1  1  1  1  1  9
dr_offsets =  0  4  8 12 16 24
dr_types =    7  7  7  7  7 17
dr_dtype =    73

printing dh vars  1
dr_blocks =   1  1  1  9 81
dr_offsets =  0  4  8 16 88
dr_types =    7  7  7 17 17
dr_dtype =    74
```

The random size of dtlrdr on proc1 shouldn't matter, though, because it's not actually receiving anything. I can't seem to figure out what's going on or why process 1 can't get through the gather without an invalid memory reference. Any ideas? And please, let me know if you guys need any more information from me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've forgotten the error status flags in the last 3 subroutines (i.e. the last argument, ierr) that you have shared.

I'll wager that you have made use of the Fortran include header file mpif.h rather than using the mpi module. If you had done the latter you would have automatic checking of the number of arguments and received an error message along the lines of

"There is no matching specific subroutine for this generic subroutine call."

due to the incorrect number of arguments.

Comment: Thanks! I'm building a module into quantum espresso, and their `parallel_include` module imports mpi as mpi.h. I went ahead and added the ierr arguments, and printed them out. The code gather's fine for the non-root process just fine (ierr=0), but crashes on the gather for the root process.

Comment: I see you're using the type MPI_ADDRESS_KIND (likely 64 bit integer) for the type of dh_offsets and dr_offsets. They should be of type integer (probably 32 bit) for the call to MPI_TYPE_STRUCT. Who knows what havoc could result! I believe you want to create your structure with MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT. Again, this would be caught by using the mpi module.

Comment: This is a very comlon error. Unfortunately, expilcit interfaces are not always available for these procedureds even in the mpi module. The new MPI3 module mpi_f08 will solve it in the future.

Comment: So I ended up getting it to run by changing all the references from MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION to MPI_REAL.